# Laptop will not go to updated web page. Cache cleared, etc. MYSTERY

Tags: dns, browser-cache

I recently changed service providers from hostgator to another server. I Ftp'd to my new site before I cancelled with HostGator to make sure I had all my stuff moved over. Then, I cancelled my service and went to GoDaddy to switch nameservers. 
I THOUGHT I was going to my new site until one day I got this weird page that had the hostgator logo. I figured out that I was still going to the old HostGator site and not my new site. I put in service tickets to GoDaddy the new service-provider and they say everything is fine that they can see the site.

**Facts:** 
Chrome, IE11, Firefox all give the same HostGator page when I try to go to the URL
PING goes to the Hostgator site
Traceroute goes all over and then to Hostgator.
Husband's laptop goes to NEW WEBSITE!(firefox)
My computer at work goes to NEW WEBSITE!
If I set up a wireless network with my phone and connect...still Hostgator site.
My phone goes to new website (on cell and WiFi)

**Things I tried but have not worked:** 
Switched DNS server to openDNS
Reset my Router
Cleared my cache on all browsers
Cleared all cookies on all browsers
Deleted all files from temp directories
Hard booted my laptop (Win 7)
Rolled my driver back on my Centrino network card then re-updated it

Then, I tried to use a PROXY. IT WORKED! I could see my site. WHY??????
Why without the proxy can I not see my site when other computers using my same router in my home can see it.

So, It's not my router. 
It's not my hardware on my laptop.
It's not the browsers.
It's somewhere in MY computer! WHERE?????

I have Win7. Avast Free. Duplicati and Onedrive running. Help?

Comment: Do you know what TTL was attached to your old DNS entry? If you're still getting the "old" site, trying restarting your DNS client.

Comment: I don't know but unless they have it set to more than 10 days..... I have been having this issue for a while. I've been using a proxy whenever I need to work on the site or go there. Everyone else can see it apparently.
It's my laptop somehow. No viruses, no malware (clamwin and MWB scan)

Comment: Tri Dee answered the question. Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your host file, just to be sure.

Comment: That was it!
I have no idea how the block got in there. It's my own website!

You, sir, are not unlike a god.

Seriously, I appreciate it.  I have learned something today.